# Determining points where the mapping $f(z) =z^2 - e^{\pi z^2}$ is not conformal

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to determine the points where the mapping $f(z) =z^2 - e^{\pi z^2}$ is not conformal.

I know that the mapping will not be conformal at the points where $f'(z)=0$. Now $f'(z) =0\implies 2z-2\pi ze^{\pi z^2}=0 \implies z(1-\pi  e^{\pi z ^2})=0\implies z=0 \,\text{ or }\, (1-\pi e^{\pi z^2}) =0$.

But how do I solve $1-\pi e^{\pi z^2}=0$ for $z$?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those $\implies$ should be $\iff$.

Comment: $e^{\pi z^2}=\frac{1}{\pi}$ and then you apply complex logarithm.

Comment: besides $0$, take a look at the points $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{\pi z^2}=\pi$. These are the numbers $z$ such that $\pi z^2=-\log(\pi) + 2\pi I n$, $n\mathbb{N}$. Take all square roots  and see what you get

Comment: @Oliver Diaz $\sqrt {\frac {-ln \pi} \pi +2in}=x+iy$ gives $x^2-y^2=\frac {-\ln \pi} \pi $ and $xy=n$. But I'm unable to find $x$ and $y$ from the above relations.

Comment: $y^2=\frac{n^2}{x^2}$ and so, $x^4-n^2=-\frac{\log \pi}{\pi}x^2$, a second order equation on $x^2$. Things can also be solve numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have\begin{align}1-\pi e^{\pi z^2}=0&\iff\pi e^{\pi z^2}=1\\&\iff e^{\pi z^2}=\frac1\pi\\&\iff e^{\pi z^2}=e^{-\log(\pi)}\\&\iff \pi z^2=-\log(\pi)+2\pi in\quad\text{for some }n\in\Bbb Z\\&\iff z^2=-\frac{\log(\pi)}\pi+2in.\end{align}So, take the square roots of the numbers of the form $=-\frac{\log(\pi)}\pi+2in$, with $n\in\Bbb Z$.